# How can I loop through values from a table in a case statement

Tags: sql-server, case

(Sorry, new to SQL). 
 I have the following table which users can update and/or add to:

```
Project Type:
ID   Name  
1    Documents
2    DVD
3    Poster
```

I have a query that in part, needs to loop through each record and create a (pivot?):

```
...
        sum (case when Project.Name = Documents then 1 else 0 end) as NumOf + Documents
        sum (case when Project.nextvalue = nextvalue then 1 else 0 end) as NumOf + nextvalue
...
```

...and then loop through for each record in table.

so results will look like:

```
ProductName  NumOfDocuments  NumOfDVD   NumOfPoster
Product A          6            0           4
Product B         13            3           8
Product C          2            0           1
```

Is this possible?

**EDIT**

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT 
  Clients.ID, 
  Products.Name, 
  sum(case when ProjectTypes.Name = 'Abstracts' then 1 else 0 end) as NumAbstracts 
FROM Clients 
INNER JOIN Products ON Clients.ID = Products.ClientID 
INNER JOIN Projects ON Products.ID = Projects.ProductID 
INNER JOIN ProjectTypes ON Projects.ProjectTypeID = ProjectTypes.ID 
GROUP BY 
  Clients.ID, 
  Products.Name, 
  Projects.ProjectTypeID


/*
SCHEMA

Clients:       ID | Name 
Products:      ID | Name | Client ID 
Projects:      ID | Name | ProductID | ProjectTypeID 
ProjectTypes:  ID | Name
*/
```

Comment: Try `COUNT()` in connection with `GROUP BY`

Comment: it seems that you want a dynamic pivot?

Comment: @Shnugo I think you put me much closer! Thanks!

Comment: you need a dynamic pivot query, kindly add more details what is the relation between products table and types you mentioned ? in order to provide a solution

Comment: The table are below. What I need in the end is: 

SiteID - ProductName - count of ProjectType1 -  count of Projecttype2 - etc.

Tables:

`Clients:
ID | Name

Products:
ID | Name | Client ID  

Projects:
ID | Name | ProductID | ProjectTypeID 

ProjectTypes:
ID | Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with conditional aggregation, like you had listed.

```
SELECT
ProductName,
SUM(CASE WHEN Name = 'Documents' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NumOfDocuments,
SUM(CASE WHEN Name = 'DVD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NumOfDVD,
SUM(CASE WHEN Name = 'Poster' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NumOfPoster
FROM
YourTable
GROUP BY ProductName
```

**DYNAMIC SQL**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Clients') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Clients
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Products') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Products
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Projects') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Projects
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ProjectTypes') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ProjectTypes

CREATE TABLE #Clients (ID int, Name varchar(64))
CREATE TABLE #Products (ID int, Name varchar(64), ClientID int)
CREATE TABLE #Projects (ID int, Name varchar(64), ProductID int, ProjectTypeID int)
CREATE TABLE #ProjectTypes (ID int, Name varchar(64))


INSERT INTO #Clients (ID, Name) VALUES
(1,'Client1'),
(2,'Client2'),
(3,'Client3'),
(4,'Client4')

INSERT INTO #Products (ID, Name, ClientID) VALUES
(1,'Prod1',1),
(2,'Prod2',1),
(3,'Prod3',1),
(2,'Prod2',2),
(2,'Prod2',3),
(3,'Prod3',3),
(4,'Prod3',3)

INSERT INTO #Projects (ID, Name, ProductID, ProjectTypeID) VALUES
(1,'Proj1',1,1),
(1,'Proj1',2,1),
(1,'Proj1',3,1),
(2,'Proj2',2,2),
(2,'Proj2',3,2),
(2,'Proj2',4,2),
(3,'Proj3',4,3)

INSERT INTO #ProjectTypes (ID, Name) VALUES
(1,'ProjType1'),
(2,'ProjType2'),
(3,'ProjType3')


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Summary') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Summary

SELECT
    c.ID,
    prod.Name as ProductName,
    proj.Name as ProjectName,
    projT.Name as ProjType
INTO #Summary
FROM #Clients c
    INNER JOIN
    #Products prod on prod.ClientID = c.ID
    INNER JOIN
    #Projects proj on proj.ProductID = prod.ID
    INNER JOIN
    #ProjectTypes projT on projT.ID = proj.ProjectTypeID

SELECT * FROM #Summary

DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(ProjType)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ProjType FROM #Summary) AS Names

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT ProductName, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM #Summary
    PIVOT(COUNT(ProjType)
          FOR ProjType IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

So using your tables, you should be able to just run this... it may need slight tweaking.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Summary') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Summary

SELECT
    c.ID,
    prod.Name as ProductName,
    proj.Name as ProjectName,
    projT.Name as ProjType
INTO #Summary
FROM Clients c
    INNER JOIN
    Products prod on prod.ClientID = c.ID
    INNER JOIN
    Projects proj on proj.ProductID = prod.ID
    INNER JOIN
    ProjectTypes projT on projT.ID = proj.ProjectTypeID


DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(ProjType)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ProjType FROM #Summary) AS Names

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT ProductName, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM #Summary
    PIVOT(COUNT(ProjType)
          FOR ProjType IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

[Tutorial](http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Thanks!
This works IF I know the Name values ahead of time. But what if they are changing?

Comment: PIVOT using Dynamic SQL. We need to know the tables and column names. You left a lot of it out in your OP. Like ProductName is in the results but not the original table. I just made assumptions. Here's a good example. there are tons more on SO. http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/

Comment: @theDaviator i added Dynamic SQL

Comment: @scsimom Yes! I need to tweak it a bit but you got me MUCH closer. Thanks so much!