# How to set columns from dynamic query results

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I am writing a query to calculate running totals of a few things over time. The time increments are in weekly buckets (every monday), however as time goes on, nothing needs to be in the past. This means my weekly buckets will be floating and always staying in the future. I have seen a couple links for how to setup a PIVOT function, however all of those examples the columns are fixed values. How do I get my query results to be displayed as my column names?

Here is my code which outputs what I need my column names to be. I set the increment to "1" to get just 4 results for testing, but will probably open it up to 12 months.

```
DECLARE @Startdate as date
DECLARE @Enddate as date

SET @Startdate = getdate()
SET @Enddate = DATEADD(Month,1,@StartDate)

;WITH cte(myDate) AS (  SELECT CASE WHEN DATEPART(Day,@StartDate) = 1 THEN @StartDate 
                        ELSE DATEADD(Week,DATEDIFF(Week,0,@StartDate)+1,0) END AS myDate
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT DATEADD(Week,1,myDate)
                        FROM cte
                        WHERE DATEADD(Week,1,myDate) <=  @EndDate )

SELECT CONVERT(date,myDate) AS BuildWeek
FROM cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: You are going to want a dynamic pivot, which is a pivot with dynamic sql. There are a lot of posts on this. Here is one that I did for someone recently. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39513013/6167855

Comment: @scsimon thanks. I will do some more reading. just needed a breadcrumb on the right keywords to search for.

Comment: No sweat. Here is a cool tutorial / explanation. http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to go dynamic.

You are missing some vital details.  So I hope this will help with some guidance.

Below is a modified version of an answer from earlier today.

```
Declare @Startdate as date,@Enddate as date
Set @Startdate = getdate()
Set @Enddate   = DATEADD(Month,1,@StartDate)

Declare @SQL varchar(max) = ''
Declare @Col varchar(max) = '
,[Title] = sum(case when Date between ''[DateR1]'' and ''[DateR2]'' then [YourField] else null end)'


;with cte(myDate) as ( 
      Select Case When DatePart(Day,@StartDate) = 1 Then @StartDate Else DateAdd(Week,DateDiff(Week,0,@StartDate)+1,0) end as myDate
      Union All
      Select DateAdd(Week,1,myDate)
       From  cte
       Where  DateAdd(Week,1,myDate) <=  @EndDate 
)
Select @SQL = @SQL + Replace(Replace(Replace(@Col,'[DateR1]',DateR1),'[DateR2]',DateR2),'Title',Title)
 From (Select DateR1 = cast(myDate as Date)
             ,DateR2 = DateAdd(DAY,6,cast(myDate as Date))
             ,Title  = 'Week Of '+Substring(DateName(WEEKDAY,myDate),1,3)+' '+Substring(DateName(MONTH,myDate),1,3)+' '+cast(Day(myDate) as varchar(5))
        From  cte
       ) A 
Set @SQL = 'Select ID'+@SQL+' 
From  YourTable 
Group By ID
'
Print @SQL
--Exec(@SQL)
```

Returns the following SQL which would be executed

```
Select ID
,[Week Of Mon Sep 26] = sum(case when Date between '2016-09-26' and '2016-10-02' then [YourField] else null end)
,[Week Of Mon Oct 3] = sum(case when Date between '2016-10-03' and '2016-10-09' then [YourField] else null end)
,[Week Of Mon Oct 10] = sum(case when Date between '2016-10-10' and '2016-10-16' then [YourField] else null end)
,[Week Of Mon Oct 17] = sum(case when Date between '2016-10-17' and '2016-10-23' then [YourField] else null end) 
From  YourTable 
Group By ID
```

Comment: Hi John - Thank you. I think i can figure it out from here or at least make a lot of progress.

Comment: @Nicho247 Had no doubt that you could make this work for you.